# Python: Module Not Found in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

```
.
└── folder1
    └── folder2
        ├── first_model.py
        └── __init__.py
    └── folder3
        ├── model.py
        └── run.ipynb
```

I'm trying to import a module within my run.ipynb file.

```
from model import xyz
```

and within model.py I've run:

```
import folder1.folder2.first_model import abc
```

when I try to run the file on jupyter notebook I keep getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1'
```

How can I fix this problem? I've been able to import my module perfectly fine within my model.py file, but when I try to move the import into a jupyter notebook it fails. Also wanted to note that I am able to run the .ipynb file just fine in pycharm's managed jupyter server, but not after I run a localhost.

Beginner in python, thanks!!

UPDATE:
I fixed it by including this at the top of my .ipynb

```
import sys
sys.path.append('my/path/to/module/folder')
```

but I've definitely included the directory in my PYTHONPATH, anyone know why I still need to include that code in?

Comment: Have you check if your module and jupyter notebook are in the environment variables?

Comment: _`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder'`_ Is that the actual error message, or is it really `folder1`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes I meant 'folder1' sorry, just edited!

Comment: Whatever the `.` directory is at the top of your file structure, is that directory in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Yes it is there!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check whether you are in the particular environment or not? if not then add environment and then check whether that module is present in that environment or not. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had a similar problem where the modules were not imported. When you are working with a jupyter notebook you have to install import-ipynb.

Install:

```
pip install import-ipynb
```

To import:

```
import import_ipynb
```